# Lua: Include file in the same directory

Tags: import, include, lua, require

I'm using [IMAPFilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter), and I'd like to keep my global configuration in a [public repository](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde), while keeping the local (and secret) configuration in a separate file. So I'm running `imapfilter` from some directory, it includes ~/.imapfilter/config.lua, and *that* should include ./config_local.lua, where "." is the directory of *config.lua*, *not* the shell `$PWD` or the location of `imapfilter`. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
require "config_local"
require "./config_local"
```

Edit: An *absolute* path works:

```
dofile(os.getenv("HOME") .. "/.imapfilter/config_local.lua")
```

Not very elegant, but at least it's compatible with `cron`.

Comment: `require` loads modules, not files: so no paths and no extensions. To load files, use `dofile`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the path to `package.path`.

Something like this (not tested):

```
package.path = package.path .. ";" .. os.getenv("HOME") .. "/.imapfilter/?.lua"
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generalized solution for adding to `package.path`, if you want to use relative paths from where your entry .lua is located:

```lua
local separator = package.config:sub(1,1)

function get_directory_path(sep)
    local file_path = debug.getinfo(2, "S").source:sub(2)
    local dir_path = file_path:match("(.*" .. sep .. ")")
    return dir_path
end

local dir_path = get_directory_path(separator)

package.path = package.path .. ";" .. dir_path .. "?.lua"

-- or to specify a subdirectory:

package.path = package.path .. ";" .. dir_path .. ".imapfilter" .. separator .. "?.lua"
```