# Load Lua-files by relative path

Tags: lua, require, coronasdk

If I have a file structure like this:

```
./main.lua
./mylib/mylib.lua
./mylib/mylib-utils.lua
./mylib/mylib-helpers.lua
./mylib/mylib-other-stuff.lua
```

From `main.lua` the file `mylib.lua` can be loaded with full path `require('mylib.mylib')`. But inside `mylib.lua` I would also like to load other necessary modules and I don't feel like always specifying the full path (e.g. `mylib.mylib-utils`). If I ever decide to move the folder I'm going to have a lot of search and replace. Is there a way to use just the relative part of the path?

UPD. I'm using Lua with Corona SDK, if that matters.

Comment: For an approach using environmental variables, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5961650/lua-include-file-in-the-same-directory.

Comment: Corona SDK... that's scary to read in 2020.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is a way of deducing the "local path" of a file (more concretely, the string that was used to load the file).

If you are requiring a file inside `lib.foo.bar`, you might be doing something like this:

```
require 'lib.foo.bar'
```

Then you can get the path to the file as the first element (and only) `...` variable, when you are outside all functions. In other words:

```
-- lib/foo/bar.lua
local pathOfThisFile = ... -- pathOfThisFile is now 'lib.foo.bar'
```

Now, to get the "folder" you need to remove the filename. Simplest way is using match:

```
local folderOfThisFile = (...):match("(.-)[^%.]+$") -- returns 'lib.foo.'
```

And there you have it. Now you can prepend that string to other file names and use that to require:

```
require(folderOfThisFile .. 'baz')     -- require('lib.foo.baz')
require(folderOfThisFile .. 'bazinga') -- require('lib.foo.bazinga')
```

If you move `bar.lua` around, `folderOfThisFile` will get automatically updated.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for loading files. But when I access module's public properties I still need to specify the full path (e.g. `lib.foo.bar.some_value`).

Comment: That has nothing to do with loading files; it simply reflects how you have chosen to structure your Lua. You can  (for example) return a table on each require, and store it in a local var : `local baz = require(folderOfThisFile .. 'baz')` and then do `baz.some_value`

Comment: Cool, I didn't know about the `...` outside functions being the string that was used to require the file.

Comment: @kikito But it forces to use the full namespace-path even between the files of the same library. If I declare `mylib.var1` then in `mylib-utils` I have to specify `some.long.path.mylib.var1` which is very awkward. I think, I'll just stick with a single directory containing everything. It's unmaintainable but works.

Comment: @RockeR : are you sure you have read my comment correctly? It handles *precisely* that issue: it allows you to do `baz.some_value` instead of `lib.foo.bar.some_value`.

Comment: I understand. But `mylib.lua` is the main file and it requires all others, particularly `require('mylib-utils')`. To access `mylib.var1` from `mylib-utils`, I would have to `require('mylib')` and get a recursive reference.

Comment: In your situation, I would split mylib into two parts; mylib-base.lua and mylib.lua. Set the variables in mylib-base and use them in mylib, utils and wherever you need them.

Comment: @SethCarnegie @RocketR I have just realized that you actually don't need to "encapsulate" `...` into a table. It's shorter and simpler to use `...` directly (you get rid of a table conversion and access). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Just add to this solution, people can also require modules using '/' instead of '.', so a more general approach is: `local folderOfThisFile = (...):match("(.-)[^%(.|/)]+$")"`

Comment: @houqp That behaviour might work on certain implementations or environments, but it is not universally portable. The best option for everyone is always using dots as path separators.

Comment: @kikito, you are right. But from the Lua module's perspective, it would be better to support both '.' and '/' so even "unportable" code can use it ;)

Comment: @houqp I disagree. In my opinion it is better that modules enforce standards and raise an error. It's the same scenario where you are expecting a number in a parameter, and they give you a string. You should throw an error saying "a number is expected here", not silently convert it to a number with `tonumber`.

Answer (score 27):

You can do

```
package.path = './mylib/?.lua;' .. package.path
```

Or

```
local oldreq = require
local require = function(s) return oldreq('mylib.' .. s) end
```

Then

```
-- do all the requires
require('mylib-utils')
require('mylib-helpers')
require('mylib-other-stuff')

-- and optionally restore the old require, if you did it the second way
require = oldreq
```

Comment: Strange. I tried changing `package.path` already and thought I was doing something wrong because it says `no field package.preload['mylib-utils']`, `no file './mylib/mylib-utils.lua'`. But I'm using Lua inside the Corona SDK, maybe it has some peculiarities with loading files.

Comment: This will not work if cwd has been changed (ie. you run the script from another program/path).

Comment: This will also not work if any of the things included with the modified `require()` themselves call `require()` internally and expect it to function as normal.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using the following snippet. It should work both for files loaded with `require`, and for files called via the command line. Then use `requireRel` instead of `require` for those you wish to be loaded with a relative path.

```
local requireRel
if arg and arg[0] then
    package.path = arg[0]:match("(.-)[^\\/]+$") .. "?.lua;" .. package.path
    requireRel = require
elseif ... then
    local d = (...):match("(.-)[^%.]+$")
    function requireRel(module) return require(d .. module) end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Under the Conky's Lua environment I've managed to include my `common.lua` (in the same directory) as `require(".common")`. Note the leading dot `.` character.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:Here is my findings:

```
module1= require(".\\moduleName")
module2= dofile("..\\moduleName2.lua")
module3 =loadfile("..\\module3.lua")
```

To load from current directory.  Append a double backslash with a prefix of a fullstop.

To specify a directory above use a prefix of two fullstops and repeat this pattern for any such directory.e.g

```
module4=require("..\\..\\module4")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've published a lua module that does this

**https://github.com/yogeshlonkar/lua-import**

It can be used via luarocks or simple copy/ paste as its single file without any dependencies.

I needed this for neovim configurations