# How can I use require in Lua to access Luvit's built-in modules?

Tags: lua, require, luvit

I am running a Luvit environment on a Ubuntu 16.04 Server VPS used to host my project. This is an image of my current file tree

[image: project tree]

I am currently inside (via the cd command) the WrapperTest folder, and running the main.lua file. This requires the server file within net/socket.

It feels like Lua is changing the file path every time I switch files. Networking is a **MUST** in this project, and my files can't even detect built-in modules.

Luvit provides many built-in modules such as `coro-http`, which provides HTTP support for Lua.

Why is it when I require a different file I cannot detect normal modules and my entire file path changes?

**Edit**: When I `require 'main'` in WrapperTest, it successfully `requires` `WrapperTest/net/socket/server`. This server file depends on 'discordio.lua' within `WrapperTest/net/`. 'discordio.lua' requires a file in the *same directory* called `http-lib` with the path `require "net/http-lib"`. On `http-lib's` very first line, it requires a module called `coro-http` which is built into Luvit's interpreter. This fails and I can't figure out why.

Stack trace (unofficial since it's a Luvit error, not pure Lua):

```
[string "bundle:deps/require.lua"]:278:
  No such module 'net/discordio' in '/usr/local/WrapperTest/net/socket/server.lua'
  ./net/http-lib.lua:1: module 'coro-http' not found:
```

Comment: To help reduce vagueness and better illustrate, can you also add a simple example to the question? eg. when you `require 'xyz'`, it fails to `require 'different_path.some_module'`afterwards, or something like that. Also add the error messages/stacktrace you get.

Comment: Done @greatwolf

Comment: If `coro-http` is part of Luvit's interpreter, then that's not a "relative path problem". That's a problem with your Luvit interpreter. You ought to be able to require it from anywhere, if Luvit has registered that module with the system properly.

Comment: My bad-- I used the wrong terms. The only "built-in" module Luvit has is "uv". By "built-in", I meant that when I'm in the WrapperTest directory and run the Luvit interpreter, I can require all the Luvit modules easily without any playing around with the paths.

Comment: I would like to clarify, however, that this problem still exists. The only way I'm getting myself out of this relative path mess is if I literally grab all the module files I can and stuff them into a single directory.

Comment: Lua does not allow you to use relative module path.  Yes, it's very inconvenient.  The simplest workaround is to place all your modules in "global modules folder" and require them specifying paths starting from that folder.

Comment: Have you seen this answer? Maybe it will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145432/load-lua-files-by-relative-path?rq=1 Also note the use of `.` instead of `/`.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff It would appear Luvit rolls their own [`require`](https://luvit.io/api/require.html), that the documentation indicates as supporting relative paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`http`](https://luvit.io/api/http.html) is the *'built-in'* library provided by Luvit, mirroring the [`http`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html) library found in Node.

[`coro-http`](https://luvit.io/lit.html#coro-http) is an auxiliary library available for install using the Luvit package manager, [`lit`](https://github.com/luvit/lit), from the public package repository.

```
$ lit install creationix/coro-http
```

The [`lit`](https://github.com/luvit/lit) [`install`](https://github.com/luvit/lit#lit-install) command will download and install the library to a local directory called `deps`.

Luvit provides a custom [`require`](https://luvit.io/api/require.html) which *should* include `deps` (and recursively ascending `deps` directories) in its search patterns.

---

If all else fails, you can try manually adjusting your search paths by changing the [`package.path`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.path) field:

```
package.path = './deps/?.lua;' .. package.path
```

Comment: Thanks for the only answer. Unfortunately it really isn't working. I tried `lit install`'ing the coro-http module and it saved many files to a deps directory within my wrapper folder. Then I tried require those, and then another require error was returned essentially staying that coro-http couldn't recognize its dependencies because i moved the deps folder containing everything elsewhere.

Then to top it off, my entire project starts returning `require` errors and as a result I'm actually on the verge of ending my project and throwing almost 2,000 lines of code into the trash.

Comment: i'm just angry that lua (or luvit?) can't implement actual file path systems. this is the only major project i've worked on in a while and to lose it all in a flash simply because the require function is playing up is extremely annoying.it has also made me lose almost all my confidence in lua's file management systems because this is totally unbelievable-- why can't require just open normal folders with normal stuff instead of having to overly complicate things.

Comment: @Cryogenic Lua's `require` has very simplistic semantics, because the underlying ANSI C code has a __very__ limited notion of what a file system is. Take a look at the documentation for `require`, `package.path`, and `package.loaders` in the [modules section](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.3). It's unclear to me how Luvit has, or has not, modified this behaviour, but you should be able to adjust it however you need at runtime, if you get a good understanding of of how those three things work together.

Comment: i see, thank you for the help anyway. i'll just try reformatting my project for now and mark your answer as correct since it did provide more help than the comments :p