# in lua (love2D), i want to import a library in a subfolder, the file in there will not find the next module it requires

Tags: lua, love2d

So in lua, i want to import a module.

I want to have my "polygon" lib in a subfolder, so i reference it like this

local polygon = require('polygon.polygon')

however, it needs another module called 'delaunay', it cannot find it as it checks the main folder

Is there anyway short of editing my library, to get this to work? (some kind of ability to add search paths?)

Thanks

Comment: provide the error message and more info on your folder structure

Comment: Lua has problems with supporting relative paths for modules.

Comment: If delaunay is in the polygon subfolder, you could use require('polygon.delauny').

A better solution might be to make sure both files are findable through package.path (as explained in the other answers) and just use require('polygon') and require('delaunay').

That way, if you were to change your directory structure, you only need to change package.path.

Answer (score 0):

In any way, it appears that you will have to deal with the subfolders explicitly.

As in, either the module `polygon` will have to import `delaunay` as `polygon.delaunay`.

Or module names will have to be appended to package.path so that lua could search through subfolders for filenames:

```
package.path=package.path..";./polygon/?.lua"
```

More info is [here](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.3).

It is pointed out in comments, you'd probably want to ensure that path concatenation happens only once.
Also, one should be wary of name shadowing.

Finally, while we are at stirring up the past, a pretty nifty trick to solve the issue was proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9146653/4687565) five years before the question.

Comment: this is bad idea. package.path is global. Each request, this code executed and concate infinitely. At the end, it will explose. I have a bad experience in PROD with this code. Please use lua_package_path instead. Read this article also https://medium.com/@fabricebaumann/how-we-reduced-the-cpu-usage-of-our-lua-code-cc30d001a328

Comment: @uwevil I'm not sure how web servicing works, but in LÖVE2D you would put this code inside `love.load()` function that is run only once at the initialization of the program. It seems from google, that `lua_package_path` is nginx-specific feature.

Answer (score 0):

To know where to look for modules, Lua's `require` uses the variables `package.path` (.lua) and `package.cpath` (.so/.dll). You can change them in your program to look in the directory you have it in. For consistency's sake, you can look at their contents to know which OS-specific separator to use. For example:

```
local sep = package.path:find("\\") and "\\" or "/"
package.path = package.path .. ";." .. sep .. "polygon" .. sep .. "?.lua"
```

This would include `./polygon/?.lua` into the search path, and a call to `require "delaunay"` would therefore have the require function look for `./polygon/delaunay.lua` in addition to existing paths. Bear in mind that in `require` strings, `.` denotes a separator as far as file searching is concerned, so calling `require "polygon.delaunay"` in this scenario will mean searching for `./polygon/polygon/delaunay.lua`.

From what I understand of your question, changing the `package.path` variable to include the path to where your `delaunay` library is stored would solve your issue, although to give a specific solution more information about your project and directory structure is required.

Comment: You can use "/" as a seperator on both windows and unix systems in path / cpath

Answer (score 0):

All what loaded into `package.loaded` can be load with `require()` because `require()` looks first in `package.loaded`...

```
-- Lua 5.3 ( lua -i )
> package.loaded.code=load(code.dump)()
> test=require('code')
> test
function: 0x565cb820
```

So you can use `load()` or `loadfile('/path/to/your_code.lua')` to do this. Another nice feature of this method is to load dumped code...

```
> package.loaded.shell=loadfile('shell.bin')
> shell=require('shell')
> shell('cat shell.bin')
uaS�
�
xV(w@F@�d�@��F�@G���d@��F�@G���d@&�typestringoexecute
/bin/bash>
```